# How do I redirect all folder requests to a data source in nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have to common resource folders `images` and `reveal.js` on my server that I'm trying to redirect urls that's include those folder names in their url to the same source.  For example:

```
/images/1.gif --> /path/to/images/1.gif
/some/other/url/images/1.gif --> /path/to/images/1.gif
```

similar for `reveal.js`:

```
/reveal.js/path/to/element.js --> /path/to/reveal.js/path/to/element.js
/some/other/url/reveal.js/element.js --> /path/to/reveal.js/element.js
```

How do I do this using Nginx?

---

```
server {
    location / {
        root /data/www;
    }

    location ~* "^.+\/images\/" {
        root /data/images; 
    }
}
```

This is my configuration file.  Requests to `site.com/images/image.gif` and site.com/some/other/url/images/image.gif`should all point to the file`/data/images/image.gif`

Comment: Check your access / error logs. I guess having root /data/images means the url example.com/images/abc means it's looking for the file at /data/images/images/abc  . Also try without the +, though I'm not a regular expression expert - not even close.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly trivial redirect, and is covered by the [Nginx redirect documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html). Something like this should work, and you can alter the regular expression until it does what you need - adding specific file types for example.

```
location ~* "^\/(resources|images)\/(.*)" {
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Update based on comments below. You'll want something like Firefox and the Live HTTP Headers plugin to examine headers to see what location is being used - you'll need the headers module compiled in, info on that [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source).

```
location ~* "^\/(resources|images)\/(.*)" {
  root /var/www/this/folder;
  add_header Z_LOCATION "LOCATION NAME";
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to point to the actual location of the folder on the server.  Is this possible?

Comment: @kronos updated above. Haven't tested but it should work. A basic Nginx tutorial would probably teach you a lot, this is fairly simple Nginx configuration.

Comment: I've been through the basic tutorial and it doesn't seem to work for me.  For example I followed the example of all `.jpeg .jpg .png` etc, to have the root folder of /data/images however it only worked if I entered the url `site.com/image.png` and not `site.com/some/other/url/images/image.png`

Comment: You're example above doesn't work for me either... :/

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't enough information to help. Post any error logs or access logs that give information. Add your full Nginx config to the question, it could be location block order precedence causing problems ( http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html ). You should also be using a regular expression tool to work out if the regex above matches your URL, and if not change the regex to match. Here's one https://regex101.com/

Comment: I've updated my question.  I'm still not getting things to work properly here.

Comment: You kinda pointed me in the right direction, but in the end I needed to use `alias`.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: Good to hear you sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to be using here is the `alias` directive, however when you use `alias` and regex you'll need to pip in the captured file into the alias like so:

```
location ~* "^.+/images/(.+)$" {
    alias /data/images/$1;
}
```

The same can be done for `reveal.js` instead of `images`.